# What's wrong with my 16x2 LCD program and solder?

Tags: lcd

I'm a total noob on Arduino here, and this is my first project on 16x2 LCD, 4x4 keypad and others. So, the story is, after I uploaded the program for my group's Arduino alarm clock to the Arduino board, the LCD displays black boxes on the first row of the LCD. Plus, when I disconnected the board from my computer and connected the board to a 5V adaptor, the LCD didn't display anything.

I've already searched the possible causes from the Internet, and mainly they said that either the initialization of the LCD is wrong or there are problems on the soldering. My friend and I concluded that there are no problem with the soldering, but we don't know where the problem is in the program.

The thing is, we didn't have any connection for the backlight of the LCD since we have no potentiometer. I tried to control the contrast and brightness of the LCD by using the Arduino, but I can't understand anything since I'm a total noob.

This is the image of the soldering of the LCD. 
[image: soldering at the 16x2 LCD]

Below is the latest code that we uploaded on the Arduino board. Is there any fault in the program?

```
    #include <EEPROM.h>
    #include <Keypad.h>
    #include <DS1307.h>
    #include <Wire.h>
    #include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
    #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
    DS1307 rtc(SDA, SCL);
    LiquidCrystal lcd(A3, A2, A1, A0, 5, 4);
    Time t;

    #define buz 3

    int Hor, Min, Sec, h, m, s;
    int ASCII = 48;
    char* tim;
    char* dat;
    const char key = 0;
    char buffer[2];
    const byte numRows= 4;
    const byte numCols= 4;
    char keymap[numRows][numCols]=
    {
    {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
    {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
    {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
    {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
    };
    byte rowPins[numRows] = {12, 11, 10, 9};
    byte colPins[numCols]= {8, 7, 6, 5};
    Keypad myKeypad= Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap),rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);

    void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
    rtc.begin();
    pinMode(buz, OUTPUT);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    welcome();

    rtc.setDOW(SATURDAY); //Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
    rtc.setTime(10, 54, 0); //Set the time to 12:00:00     (24hr format)
    rtc.setDate(7, 1, 2017); //Day, Month, Year
    }

    void loop() {
    t = rtc.getTime();
    Hor = t.hour;
    Min = t.min;
    Sec = t.sec;
    tim = rtc.getTimeStr();
    dat = rtc.getDateStr();
    char key = myKeypad.getKey();

    if (key == 'C'){
    digitalWrite(buz, LOW);
    EEPROM.write(2, ASCII+6);
    EEPROM.write(3, ASCII);
    }

    if(key == '#'){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Enter New Time");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    int j =0;
    int i=0;
    while( j<6)
    {
    if(i==2 || i == 5){
    lcd.print(":");
    lcd.display();
    i++;
    }
    key=myKeypad.getKey();
    if(key)
    {
    lcd.print(key);
    lcd.display();
    EEPROM.write(j,key);
    j++;
    i++;
    }
    }
    }

    changealarm();
    checkalarm();
    timedate();
    }

    void checkalarm(){
    if( Hor == h && Min == m)
    {
    delay(3000);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Hold C");
    digitalWrite(buz, HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    }
    }

    void changealarm(){
    buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(0);
    buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(1);
    h = atoi(buffer);
    buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(2);
    buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(3);
    m = atoi(buffer);
    buffer[0]=EEPROM.read(4);
    buffer[1]=EEPROM.read(5);
    s = atoi(buffer);
    }

    void timedate(){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Time: ");
    lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Date: ");
    lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
    delay(3000);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Alarm: ");
    lcd.print(h);
    lcd.print(".");
    lcd.print(m);
    lcd.print(".");
    lcd.print(s);
    delay(3000);
    }

    void welcome(){
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Welcome");

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("To");
    delay(3000);

    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("TIMeProject");
    delay(3000);
    }
```

Comment: Before you attempt any more testing, I suggest you trim the excess wire that is not insulated to reduce the possibility of any short circuits...

Comment: Program code is always singular. "Codes" are what you use to open a keypad lock or to decode a secret message.

Comment: Write a simple program that only initializes the LCD and writes a simple text to the display.  That will help you figure out if you have a software problem or a hardware problem.

Comment: Also, you should get and use a potentiometer for the contrast.  The Arduino doesn't output a simple analog signal.  "Analogwrite" sends a pulse width modulated signal.  It is a bunch of pulses with two states: on (+5V) and off (0V.)

Comment: To trim excess wire, you want cutters that look like [this pair](https://www.amazon.com/XURON-170-II-Micro-Shear-Flush-Cutter/dp/B07BSSG48F).

Comment: you can also use fingernail clippers to trim copper wire

Comment: Thank you everyone! The boxes have disappeared after I add the potentiometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LCD is not being initialized properly. It is probably a firmware or wiring error.

Check that the RW pin is grounded. Connect your pot ELEMENT one side to GND (Vss on the LCD) and one to +5V (Vdd on the LCD) through a 1K resistor.

The pot WIPER goes to Vo on the LCD display.

The 1K resistor is not 100% necessary but it protects the pot if you make a mistake.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAUxor.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

If that doesn't work, check the pin numbers on the Arduino and how it matches to the respective LCD pin numbers very carefully. RW should go to ground and not to the Arduino.

---

The A and K pins are for the backlight, which may or may not be present. Leave that for now.

Comment: We've desoldered the wires and solder them again to the respective pins on LCD. We've also connected the 10k ohm potentiometer to the Vo of the LCD. I leave out the A and K pin for now. After adjusting the potentiometer, the LCD displays the "Welcome" part. However, after a while, some strange letters pop out. We are not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general, seeing the boxes like that on these character LCDs often is a contrast issue. As noted in the comments, AnalogWrite generates a PWM pulse train which won't correctly control the contrast. If you can't get a potentiometer, try using two fixed resistors as a voltage divider to try getting closer to a usable contrast level. I'd start with two equal resistors to give 2.5 volts to the contrast pin.

Comment: There's only one line of boxes. Can that still be a contrast issue?  Were it me, I'd want to see if the boxes don't appear until after the firmware initializes.

Comment: Ah. I missed that there was only one row in the photo. This probably discounts it being just contrast. Time to look back at the code

Comment: I've add a 10k ohm potentiometer and after adjusting a bit, the LCD can display properly again. Thank you!